# how to avoid unsupported formats in audio player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am creating an audio player and i am using this code to get all the songs

```
String[] STAR = {"*"};

    Cursor cursor;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

      File file;

    cursor =context.getContentResolver().query(uri, STAR, selection, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int i = 0;
            do {



                String songName = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));

                path[i] = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));


                String albumName = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                albumId[i] = cursor
                        .getInt(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

                String artist= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                String albumname= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                artistId[i]=cursor.getInt(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));



        }cursor.close();
```

This gets me the songs but i get audio of unsupported formats too. such as .wav any idea how to avoid unsupported formats

Comment: You need add check on MimeType. Please see an example how to add check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MimeType` to do this. See below example code how it is done for mp3.

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
String[] projection = null;
String sortOrder = null;
String selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
String mimeType = imeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp3"); 
String[] selectionArgsMp3 = new String[]{ mimeType };
Cursor mp3Songs = contentResolver.query(uri, projection,selectionMimeType,selectionArgsmp3, sortOrder);
```

**Another approach it that you can check is there any compatible application installed on device using below code while opening/playing application.**

```
private void openRelevantFileHandler(String pathToMusicFile)
{
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(pathToMusicFile);
    String type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + pathToMusicFile), type);

    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
    boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
    if (!isIntentSafe) {
        Utility.showToast(context, "No application available on your device to open this type of file.");
    }
    else 
    {
        context.startActivity(intent);//Start related application
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you in some way :)